# Use custom test runners for android Unit Test

Tags: android-studio, android-testing, android-junit, android-unit-testing, androidjunitrunner

Is it possible to use a custom test runner for android unit test? (Or junit tests)?

I have tried setting a custom test runner in my default config like

testInstrumentationRunner = "ca.xyz.CustomTestRunner"

But it doesn't work.  I checked in the unit test configuraitons and I didn't see an option for this.

Am I missing something?